# How to get student_id from database through username after login?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a site that consists of the form so that users can log in and submit it. I have 3 different user types two users need to see all submitted forms. I did that using PHP/MySQL. I have no problem there.
However, the other user type which is the student needs to see the forms that s/he submitted not other forms submitted by other users.

Student log in the site with a username.  **I want to do when s/he logs in, I want to get his StudentID and keep it so that later I use it to get specific data.**

In this code, I will use StudentID to get data.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"
    SELECT i.formid
     ,i.name
     ,u.studentID
     ,i.grade
 FROM 
    informationform i 
 JOIN users u 
 ON i.studentID = u.studentID
 ");
```

Comment: what is the informationform  table and what does it to do with getting the student's id by the username?

Comment: Note that the other day you have been given the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61155315/how-to-get-specific-row-from-the-sql) to this question. Getting some data from a table based on a condition is the most basic operation in PHP mysql, you have to learn it by heart

Comment: the  thing  I want user will log in with username, I will display the student id of the user  instead of username.  Then, I will use that info in my select query. I think I could not express my self

Comment: When I get user's StudentId, I will use it to get data from informationform table